# Custom Query on Wordpress using Multiple Taxonomies and a Date as a Custom Attribute VarChar

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My problem puts together a lot of things, which is most likely why I can't make it work for the hell of it.

I'm not fluent in long SQL Queries, and I'm not a big fan of Wordpress, but I was asked to fix the ordering on a specific page, and to make that happen I need to order by a custom attribute.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'meta_key' => 'key_for_meta',

    'orderby' => 'STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, "%d/%m/%Y")',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'first_taxonomy' => $first_taxonomy,
    'second_taxonomy' => $second_taxonomy
);
```

It would be the ideal solution, and if anyone knows how to make this work, I would love to know.

I already tried the `key_for_meta` instead of `meta_value` on the `orderby`, and tried pointing to the right table.column and so on.

I lost all hope after a ton of tries, and am trying to create a query. It's going like this:

```
SELECT p.*,
m.meta_key, m.meta_value, 
tt.taxonomy as s_tax,
t.slug
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS m ON p.ID = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'key_for_meta'
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID=tr.object_id
**INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id**

WHERE 1 = 1
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'custom_post_type'
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'

    **AND t.slug = '$first_taxonomy'
    AND t.slug = '$second_taxonomy'**

GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(m.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC";
```

Any solution will be greatly appreciated. I don't care how the problem is solved, I just want it to work flawlessly. If it can also look nice, perfect, but I gave up on that.

The dates are in the format DD/MM/YYYY.
As requested, some columns from wp_postmeta:

```
meta_id    post_id    meta_key    meta_value
5101       3521       data_prova  12/01/2013
5114       3526       data_prova  02/03/2013
5165       3554       data_prova  02/03/2013
```

Also, I couldn't make the taxonomies work on the query I made, yet.

Great news: I made almost everything work. Only problem is, I can't get it to work with BOTH taxonomies, though if I try with only one, it works.

Comment: Fernando, can you edit your question to give us a few examples of your wp_postmeta rows?  'twould help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone having the same problem:

I couldn't figure out how to do with only SQL, so I tested the Taxonomies using WordPress's `has_term()`. My solution is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, 
m.meta_key, m.meta_value, 
tt.taxonomy, tt.term_id,
t.slug
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS m 
    ON p.ID = m.post_id 
    AND m.meta_key = 'key_for_meta'
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr 
    ON p.ID = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt 
    ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS t 
    ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND p.post_type = 'custom_post_type'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND (
    t.slug = '$first_taxonomy'
    )
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(m.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC
```

Plus this PHP to Start and Run The Loop:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($queryRaw);

if ($wpdb->num_rows > 0) {

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $stored_post = clone $GLOBALS['post'];
    $GLOBALS['post'] = $post;

    setup_postdata($post);
    if (has_term( $first_taxonomy, 'first_taxonomy', $post->ID) && has_term( $second_taxonomy, 'second_taxonomy', $post->ID)) {
    ...
```

And the rest is as usual. All Methods work since I'm setting the global `$post`.

I'll leave the question open incase other people have something to contribute, I'd be glad to see more ideas of how to deal with this, I really wanted a pure-Wordpress or at least pure-SQL solution (Regarding the testing I had to do using PHP).